# QTableView -- prevent departure from cell and closure of Delegate editor

Tags: pyqt5

I have a QAbstractTableModel+QTableView, and a Delegate assigned which creates a QLabel widget to use as the editor.

I simply want to do this:  When the Delegate editor is active, under certain circumstances (when the data in the cell doesn't validate), inhibit departure from the cell and stay in the editing session.  In other words, if circumstances dictate and the user tries to leave the cell (by whatever means -- tab, arrow key, mouse click, etc), *don't do anything at all*.  Just stay put, as though nothing ever happened.

I thought this would be easy, but I have not been able to figure out how to do it.

My first thought was that I could catch the Delegate's `closeEditor` signal.  That code is shown below.  It's a bit long (so as to be standalone executable), but most of what's shown is just standard model/view/delegate stuff.  The interesting part is at the bottom.  I've defined a slot (`on_closeEditor()`), and connected it to the `closeEditor` signal (see the `### ... ###` comments).

The Delegate catches when the Enter key is pressed and emits the `closeEditor` signal explicitly.  When that happens, the `on_closeEditor()` slot gets called.  So the connection seems to be made properly.

But when the cell is departed by other means (e.g,. tab key or mouse click), although the Delegate editor *does* appear to be closed, the slot never gets called.

(There's also the matter that, even if my code *could* gain control when a Delegate editor is closing, it's not clear to me how I'd stop it from happening.  But one thing at a time ...)

Is there a straightforward way to do this? I feel like I must be missing something ...

Thanks!

**Sample Code**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data = [[]], headers = None, parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            value = self.__data[row][column]
            return value
        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(230, 240, 250))


    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            if value is None:
                value = ''
            self.__data[row][column] = value
            return True
        return False


    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.blocked = False

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        mod = int(event.modifiers())
        row = self.currentIndex().row()

        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Q and mod == QtCore.Qt.CTRL:
            self.close()
            exit()

        super().keyPressEvent(event)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        self.editor = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent)
        return self.editor

    def setEditorData(self, label, index):
        print('setEditorData()')
        model = index.model()
        v = model.data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        model.setData(index, None, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    def setModelData(self, label, model, index):
        print('setModelData()')
        value = label.text()
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()
        model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)

    def eventFilter(self, target, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            key = event.key()
            mod = int(event.modifiers())

            if (
                key >= QtCore.Qt.Key_Space and key <= QtCore.Qt.Key_AsciiTilde and 
                (mod == QtCore.Qt.NoModifier or mod == QtCore.Qt.SHIFT)
            ):
                text = self.editor.text()
                self.editor.setText(text + event.text())
                return True

            # Enter (or ctrl-Enter) explicitly emits commitData, closeEditor
            elif (
                key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return and
                (mod == QtCore.Qt.NoModifier or mod == QtCore.Qt.CTRL)
            ):
                self.commitData.emit(target)
                self.closeEditor.emit(target)
                return True

        return False

    ### closeEditor slot ###
    def on_closeEditor(self, editor, hint):
        print('closeEditor()')


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')

    tableView = TableView()
    tableView.resize(550, 160)

    delegate = Delegate()
    tableView.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    ### connect closeEditor signal to slot ###
    delegate.closeEditor.connect(delegate.on_closeEditor)

    tableView.show()

    rowCount = 3
    columnCount = 4
    data = [
        ['foo', 'goo', 'zoo', 'moo'],
        ['bar', 'zar', 'jar', 'gar'],
        ['qux', 'lux', 'mux', 'sux']
        ]

    model = TableModel(data)
    tableView.setModel(model)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***[edit]***

My next thought was that I could install an event filter for the Delegate, and filter out the FocusAboutToChange and/or FocusOut events.  In fact, I really thought this was going to be the perfect solution.

But it didn't work.  :-(

`print()` statements show that the events are properly detected.  I thought if `eventFilter()` returned `True`, the events would be stopped.  But it seems not to be so.  The cursor leaves the edited cell anyhow.

**Code**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data = [[]], headers = None, parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            value = self.__data[row][column]
            return value
        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(230, 240, 250))

    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            if value is None:
                value = ''
            self.__data[row][column] = value
            return True
        return False

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.blocked = False

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        mod = int(event.modifiers())

        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Q and mod == QtCore.Qt.CTRL:
            self.close()
            exit()

        super().keyPressEvent(event)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        self.editor = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent)
        return self.editor

    def setEditorData(self, label, index):
        model = index.model()
        v = model.data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        model.setData(index, None, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    def setModelData(self, label, model, index):
        value = label.text()
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()
        model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)

    def eventFilter(self, target, event):

        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            key = event.key()
            mod = int(event.modifiers())

            # ASCII input
            if (
                key >= QtCore.Qt.Key_Space and key <= QtCore.Qt.Key_AsciiTilde and 
                (mod == QtCore.Qt.NoModifier or mod == QtCore.Qt.SHIFT)
            ):
                text = self.editor.text()
                self.editor.setText(text + event.text())
                return True

        ### Ostensibly filter out FocusAboutToChange and FocusOut events ###
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusAboutToChange:
            print('FocusAboutToChange')
            return True
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut:
            print('FocusOut')
            return True

        return False


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')

    rowCount = 3
    columnCount = 4
    data = [
        ['foo', 'goo', 'zoo', 'moo'],
        ['bar', 'zar', 'jar', 'gar'],
        ['qux', 'lux', 'mux', 'sux']
        ]

    tableView = TableView()
    tableView.resize(550, 160)

    delegate = Delegate()
    tableView.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    delegate.installEventFilter(delegate)

    tableView.show()
    model = TableModel(data)
    tableView.setModel(model)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: From what I understand, you want that if the entry is not correct (it is not validated correctly) the editing status is kept in that item, is that correct? If I am correct, how is the validation? I ask it since it seems that you are doing it in the editorEvent method

Comment: Yes, that's just it.  If the data in the cell is not valid at the time the user tries to depart the cell (by any means), I want that cell to remain the current cell, and the editor to remain open.  In other words, I want it to act as though the event that tried to cause departure from the cell never happened at all.

After thinking about this more, I thought maybe I could accomplish this by intercepting the FocusAboutToChange and FocusOut events.  My attempt is posted below; it didn't work either.

Comment: I have a question, an editor is a widget that allows you to modify the information that shows as the QLineEdit, QSpinBox, etc. but a QLabel is not that kind of widget since it does not allow editing. Why do you use it?

Comment: some feedback??

Comment: That does seem weird, I'll grant.  This is sample code extracted from a larger application.  The actual application allows some editing in the cell that is beyond what a QLineEdit supports.  Using a QLabel gives me complete flexibility over what's displayed.  As far as I can tell, with respect to the original question, QLineEdit doesn't work any better.

Comment: I do not point out that QLineEdit is the solution but that your current code does not allow any editing. Have you tested your MCVE? Can you edit any cell?

Comment: Well, sort of.  This example is cut down from the larger app, so the only thing you can do here is type in text; you can't actually change it once it's there.  But you can in the larger app.  The event filter processes keyboard input, modifies the contents of the QLabel as indicated, and then re-displays it.  The effect is as though it were being edited.  The sample is fully self-contained.  You should be able to run it and see for yourself.

Comment: okay, I just checked what you point out. I have another doubt, now your code allows you to write text but it does not allow you to delete it, how do you correct it if the data is invalid ?, why a QLabel and not a QLineEdit ?, this last I say it because the most natural thing is to use QLineEdit since it implements all the basic functionalities of the editor. If I propose the solution with QLineEdit would it be correct?

Comment: In the complete application, I catch keystrokes that would delete characters (e.g., backspace), modify the text of the QLabel appropriately, and re-display it.  The original question concerned suppressing departure from the cell while editing is occurring.  Simply being able to enter characters into the cell is enough to demonstrate that problem; deletion is not necessary.  So that logic is left out of this sample code.  If you are able to propose a solution that inhibits departure from the cell, using a QLineEdit as the editor, that would be very helpful.

Comment: In fact, if you simply change QLabel to QLineEdit in my sample code, the problem is virtually identical.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is following this and is curious how it worked out:

With help from some guys at the Riverbank Computing PyQt mailing list, I arrived at the following solution.  In involves the following:

If the data in the cell doesn't validate:

- Override the Delegate's `setModelData()` method and suppress posting the cell data to the model.  Use `label.setFocus()` to keep focus on the editor widget, and `view.setCurrentIndex()` to keep the view's current index from changing.
- Override the View's `closeEditor()` slot to prevent the editor from closing.

Solution is shown below.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys, re


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data = [[]], headers = None, parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__data = data
    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data)
    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data[0])
    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            value = self.__data[row][column]
            return value
        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(230, 240, 250))
    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            if value is None:
                value = ''
            self.__data[row][column] = value
            return True
        return False
    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        mod = int(event.modifiers())
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Q and mod == QtCore.Qt.CTRL:
            self.close()
            exit()
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def closeEditor(self, editor, hint):

        ### --- If data validates, close editor; otherwise, don't --- ###
        if editor.validate():
            print(f'>> Closing editor')
            super().closeEditor(editor, hint)
        else:
            print(f'>> Not closing editor')


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.editor = None

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        self.view = parent.parent()
        self.editor = CellEditor(parent)
        return self.editor

    def setEditorData(self, label, index):
        model = index.model()
        v = model.data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    def setModelData(self, label, model, index):
        value = label.text()
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()

        ### --- If data validates, post it to the model; otherwise, don't --- ###
        if label.validate():
            model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            print(f'>> [setModelData({value})] accepted')
        else:
            label.setFocus()
            self.view.setCurrentIndex(index)
            print(f'>> [setModelData({value})] rejected')

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)

    def eventFilter(self, target, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            key = event.key()
            mod = int(event.modifiers())

            # ASCII input -- add to cell value
            if (
                key >= QtCore.Qt.Key_Space and key <= QtCore.Qt.Key_AsciiTilde and 
                (mod == QtCore.Qt.NoModifier or mod == QtCore.Qt.SHIFT)
            ):
                text = self.editor.text()
                self.editor.setText(text + event.text())
                return True

            # [ctrl-H], Backspace -- delete a character
            elif (
                (key == QtCore.Qt.Key_H and mod == QtCore.Qt.CTRL) or
                (key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace and mod == QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
            ):
                self.editor.setText(self.editor.text()[:-1])
                return True

        return False


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class CellEditor(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet('font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; color: blue')
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

    ### --- Sample validation function --- ###
    def validate(self):
        return re.fullmatch('\d+', self.text())



# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')

    rowCount = 3
    columnCount = 4
    data = [
        ['foo', 'goo', 'zoo', 'moo'],
        ['bar', 'zar', 'jar', 'gar'],
        ['qux', 'lux', 'mux', 'sux']
        ]

    view = TableView()
    view.resize(550, 160)
    model = TableModel(data)
    view.setModel(model)
    view.show()

    delegate = Delegate()
    view.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This section is exclusive for answers, if you want to add valuable information you should do it as an edit to your question, please read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour] again